# Using window.location.replace after an Ajax response does not redirect immediately

Tags: javascript, ajax, redirect

I am implementing facebook connect for authentication. I also want to verify that the email of the user I receive from facebook matches with an internal database (essentially invite list). So I use an ajax call as below. However, the redirect does not happen immediately. The user needs to refresh the window in order to get redirected. Any ideas why and how this can be fixed? Thanks!
Note that this happens within FB.api which in turn is inside window.fbAsyncInit.

```
   $.ajax({  
                   type: "POST",  
                   url: "verifyLogin.php",  
                   data: ("email=" + myEmail),  
                   success: function(resp){  
                          if (resp == 'success')
                          {
                                window.location.replace('/index.php');
                          }
                   },  
                   error: function(e){  
                     alert('Error: ' + e);  
                   }
                   });
```

Comment: why not just window.location = "yoursite.com/index.php"?

Comment: @peshkira - that doesn't work either. The user still needs to hit refresh. Note that after the user has logged in once, subsequently when they go this page, the automatic redirect works fine. Its just for the case when the user logs in the first time.

Comment: Ok so i used the function below and it works now. Still don't know why the ajax response didnt work and now have to change the code to confirm the email address match from this function. Thanks for the help!
'code'
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
  window.location.replace('index.php');
});

Answer (score 0):

This should be immediately after the request has returned success have you tested that the response occurs immediately if you are not inside the facebook window class?

also the resp check should not be necessary if you are not returning the word "success" from verifyLogin.php

Tell us more about what you mean about immediately.

Comment: There is a (resp == 'failure') case as well which I haven't added above for simplicity. By immediately, I mean that it should be an automatic redirect for the user. However, what happens is that the page remains as is, and if you hit 'refresh' on the page, then it does the redirect. Note that after the user has logged in once, subsequently when they go this page, the automatic redirect works fine. Its just for the case when the user logs in the first time.